# hook_form_alter() does not work for the contact form?

Tags: 8, emails

I have contact form module enabled from core drupal 8 modules.

When I use the below code it has

```
   $form['field_consumer_name']['widget'][0]['#title'] = 'Individual Name';
```

I want that this code which I have written should override default title but it does not .
I would be interested in knowing how I can override title?

```
 function referral_q_form_contact_message_referral_form_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state ) {
   // print_r($form['field_consumer_name']['widget'][0]['#title']);
$form['field_consumer_name']['widget'][0]['#title'] = 'Consumer Name Works';

   $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="referral-container">';

   $form['field_consumer_name']['widget'][0]['#title'] = 'Individual Name';
   $form['field_referral_date']['widget'][0]['#title'] = 'Date';

   $form['field_diagnostic_code_1']['widget'][0]['#title'] = 'Diagnostic Code';

   _referral_q_remove_radio_na($form['field_veteran']);

   $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
 }
```

Comment: I assume 'referral_q_form_contact_message_referral_form' is the name of your module. Have you tried debugging the code above to see that it is even being hit?

Comment: referral_q is module name

Comment: contact_message_referral_form_form is name of the form_id

Comment: back to Kevin question: besides changing the title, can you prove it to yourself that ALTER is working? Can you kint / var_dump something?

Comment: yes i tried by doing print_r($form); and it showed me array which showed that it was being hit.

Comment: I would appreciate if anyone could help me out

Answer (score 1):

This is the array structure of the relevant part of the form.

> [image]

Using `$form['field_consumer_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#title'] = 'Individual Name'; worked for me.

Comment: just as a small suggestion: when you hardcode ui strings, you should always use translate function. It's a good drupal habit.